# Mongoose group and count

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Below is my mongodb structure:

```
[{
    _id: '111',
    items: [{
        productId: '123'
    }]
}, {
    _id: '222',
    items: [{
        productId: '123'
    }, {
        productId: '456'
    }]
}, {
    _id: '333',
    items: [{
        productId: '123'
    }, {
        productId: '456'
    }, {
        productId: '789'
    }]
}]
```

And I expect to group and count `productId` so that the result to be:

```
[{
    productId: '123',
    count: 3
}, {
    productId: '456',
    count: 2
}, {
    productId: '789',
    count: 1
}]
```

---

Well, I tried using `aggregation` like this, but I think I got it wrong:

```
const aggregatorOpts = [{
  $group: {
    _id: "$items.productId",
    count: { $sum: 1 }
  }
}]

Model.aggregate(aggregatorOpts).exec()
```

I got:

```
result [
  { _id: [ '123' ], count: 1 },
  { _id: [ '123', '456' ], count: 1 },
  { _id: [ '123', '456', '789' ], count: 1 }
]
```

Any help regarding how to do the aggregation probably is appreciated, and please don't assume any change in the model.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) items array before grouping :

```
const aggregatorOpts = [{
        $unwind: "$items"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$items.productId",
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    }
]

Model.aggregate(aggregatorOpts).exec()
```

which gives :

```
{ "_id" : "789", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "456", "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "123", "count" : 3 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
    Model.aggregate([
        {
            $group: {
               _id: '$items.productId',
                points: {$count: '$items'}
           }
       }
     ]);
```

This should work.

Comment: Unknown group operator `$count`. It;s syntax error maybe.

Comment: Try changing "$count:'$items" as $sum:1"

Comment: That'll return us back to the initial point. @Bertrand's answer already solved it. Thanks for your help tho!